# How to access widgets from within listener?

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

I am building a GUI with SWT by using WindowBuilder for Eclipse. When you drag'n'drop widgets onto your shell in WindowBuilder, your source code gets automatically generated. However, all the widget objects are declared in the `createContents` function. The following is an excerpt from that function:

```
Button btnStartServer = new Button(shlTest, SWT.NONE);
btnStartServer.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        // how to access serverStateDisplay right here?
        // I have access to shlTest (my Shell object), though
    }
});
btnStartServer.setText("Start Server");

Canvas serverStateDisplay = new Canvas(shlTest, SWT.NONE);
```

As you can see, I have a selection listener that get's triggered when I click a button. Now, how can I access the canvas? The obvious solution, simply writing `serverStateDisplay.doWhatever()` is not working.

---

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241905/access-a-widget-from-an-event-handler-in-java-swt) which essentially asks the same thing. However, the only solutions were to either declare the referenced widget before the listener or to declare it as a class instance variable.

This is not satisfying for me, since I build my UI with WindowBuilder. Can't WB do this automatically for me? Because when the application grows, it will be quite uncomfortable manually changing each widget declaration.

---

The same goes for the main loop. With the widgets declared inside the `createContents` function, they are not accessible once the function terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, to access a widget you should either declare it a field or try to get the Widget from the selection event.

In your case, I would prefer exposing your canvas as a field.

In Window Builder, to expose a local variable as a field: select the variable, then click on the button "Convert local to field".

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now one more question that is on my mind: Should I be converting all widgets prophylactically or only the ones that I am going to use later? What's the best-practice here?

Comment: I would convert only the widgets you need to access from inside your eventHandlers. So doing you avoid the proliferation of fields. Creating UIs is complex, and I prefer having exposed only the fields that are needed by the business logic.